# trying to install php gd extension php55-common conflicts with php-common-5.3

Tags: php, linux, amazon-ec2, php-gd

I am trying to install php gd extension on php5.5 amazon ec2 server 
using this command

```
yum install php-gd
```

log:

```
Loaded plugins: priorities, update-motd, upgrade-helper
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php-gd.x86_64 0:5.3.28-1.5.amzn1 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: php-common(x86-64) = 5.3.28-1.5.amzn1 for package: php-gd-5.3.28-1.5.amzn1.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libXpm.so.4()(64bit) for package: php-gd-5.3.28-1.5.amzn1.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libt1.so.5()(64bit) for package: php-gd-5.3.28-1.5.amzn1.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package libXpm.x86_64 0:3.5.10-2.9.amzn1 will be installed
---> Package php-common.x86_64 0:5.3.28-1.5.amzn1 will be installed
---> Package t1lib.x86_64 0:5.1.2-6.5.amzn1 will be installed
--> Processing Conflict: php55-common-5.5.14-1.75.amzn1.x86_64 conflicts php-common < 5.5.14-1.75.amzn1
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: php55-common conflicts with php-common-5.3.28-1.5.amzn1.x86_64
You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

I tried to do this

```
 sudo yum remove php-common
 sudo yum install php55
```

but nothing changed

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remove PHP 5.3:

```
sudo yum remove php-common
```

Install PHP5.5:

```
sudo yum install php55 php55-gd php55-mysqlnd php55-pdo
```

Comment: If you removed 5.3, just install 5.5.

Comment: i did and i did this command also sudo service httpd restart php -v PHP 5.3.28 (cli) (built: Mar 28 2014 23:50:27) but the site not working now what can i do ?

Comment: yum list installed | grep php.

Comment: php-cli.x86_64                       5.3.28-1.5.amzn1              amzn-updates
php-common.x86_64                    5.3.28-1.5.amzn1              amzn-updates
php-gd.x86_64                        5.3.28-1.5.amzn1              amzn-updates
php-pear.noarch                      1:1.9.4-20.15.amzn1           amzn-main
php-process.x86_64                   5.3.28-1.5.amzn1              amzn-updates
php-xml.x86_64                       5.3.28-1.5.amzn1              amzn-updates

Comment: i did it it's still loading my php code in my browser

Comment: thanks it's running, but now i have another problem let me first search and then back to you thanks again

Comment: include(PDO.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory is there is a php extinction for PDO that is not installed ?

Comment: sudo yum install php55-pdo

Comment: this command solved my pdo problem "sudo yum install php55-mysqlnd" , but now phpmyadmin gives me a white page

Comment: Call to undefined function mb_detect_encoding() in /var/www/html/phpmyadmin/libraries/php-gettext/gettext.inc

Comment: phpmyadmin issue solved by installing this yum install php55-mbstring, but the php-gd issue not solved

Comment: sudo yum install php55-gd

Answer (score 3):

I also have problem in installing gd Library and I solve it by using the following code my php version is 5.6 so that's why i write php56-gd. if your php version is 5 you can do it by using "yum install php5-gd"

```
     yum install php56-gd
```